# Why does dispatch throw "java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine ..." and "unexpected status" exceptions for a particular URL?

Tags: java, scala, http, web, scala-dispatch

I have the following non-working code:

```
object Main extends App {
  import dispatch._

  def test(address: String) = {
    Await.result(Http.default(url(address).GET OK as.String), Duration.Inf)
  }

  // This works fine
  val s1 = test("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=MSFT&f=sohgbav")
  println(s1)

  // This throws Exception 1
  val s2 = test("http://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo&datatype=csv")
  println(s2) 

  // This throws Exception 2
  val s3 = test("https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo&datatype=csv")
  println(s3) 
}
```

I would like to know why "s1" works fine, whereas "s2" and "s3" throw exceptions. The exceptions thrown are:

Exception 1:

```
[error]   ! access URL
[error]    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: dispatch.StatusCode: Unexpected response status: 301 (NettyResponseFuture.java:172)
[error] org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:172)
[error] dispatch.HttpExecutor.$anonfun$apply$3(execution.scala:123)
```

Exception 2:

```
[error]   ! access URL
[error]    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: General SSLEngine problem (NettyResponseFuture.java:172)
[error] org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:172)
[error] dispatch.HttpExecutor.$anonfun$apply$3(execution.scala:123)
```

Also, all three URLs work as expected when I access them through the Safari web browser. Why does the first URL work fine through dispatch, but the last two don't?

Comment: I understand why I am getting status 301 for "s2". Alpha Vantage wants me to use "https" instead of "http". I am still slightly surprised, though, that Safari seems to recover automatically from 301 and successfully downloads the data, whereas Dispatch doesn't. But the main issue is Exception 2 for "s3", when I do use "https".

Comment: I found this related question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288803/trust-all-ssl-certificates-in-java-playframework-2-2). But how do I do something similar to that with dispatch?

Comment: Was there a change between dispatch 0.11 and 0.13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trust all certificates, as in the linked Play example, then try this:

```
Http.withConfiguration(config => config.setAcceptAnyCertificate(true))(url(address).GET OK as.String)
```

Answer (score 0):

And to create an Http client that does verify the certificates, I found some sample code here: https://kevinlocke.name/bits/2012/10/03/ssl-certificate-verification-in-dispatch-and-asynchttpclient/.